# How to know the number of valence electrons of f-block elements?

Tags: electrons, periodic-table

I kinda know how to get the valence electrons for s/p/d- blocks but i don't know about the f-block.

Wikipedia says that valence electrons for f-block is ns + (n-1)d + (n-2)f, so is it true? If so can you give examples?

This is what Wikipedia shows :

[image]

And another question : what's the electronic configuration of palladium Pd ions? If i apply what i know i'll get that
$P d^{2+}$ is [Kr] 4d^8 , so is it right?

Comment: Take some of a particular lanthanoid and just count.

Comment: how? can you give example? should i count the f sub-level with them(like d block transition elements) or just the highest n level?

Comment: Example of choosing an element or example of counting? You already have the formula. Keep handy the periodic table.

Comment: so the formula is true???

Comment: The answers you find yourself are more valuable than those you were told. As these answers teach you the process of finding them. But they will teach you that only if you ask after you have thoroughly tried and failed.

Comment: Please, provide context. Lanthanides and actinides are elements for which heuristics build around "valence electrons" break horribly.